# How to allow mobile wallets to sign and access to my dapp

Tags: web3js, wallets, dapps

I'm building a dapp application on Ethereum using React & Web3js. As usual the dapp will get the injected provider from Window.web3 (MetaMask), perhaps. The problem that I'm facing now is how can I allow other mobile wallet to sign and access my dapp? For example, CryptoKitties & DDEX Exchange platform. Please advise